# During re-index, add a keyword field using painless?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-6.8

My painless script for a re-index is adding a field. How can I index that new field as a `keyword` vice text field using painless?

```
   POST _reindex
   {
     8<
    "script" : {
       "source" : "ctx._source.newfield = 'test'"
       "lang" : "painless"
    }
```

I want `newfield` to be `newfield.keyword`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Elasticsearch will map it to a `text` field, with a `keyword` sub-field, **unless** you have specified explicit mapping. Your mapping would look like this:

```json
 "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "newfield": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As a consequence, it will both be possible to perform full-text search on `newfield`, and keyword search and aggregations using the `newfield.keyword` field.

If you want it to be mapped as a `keyword`  you will have to specify your own [explicit mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch///reference/master/explicit-mapping.html#explicit-mapping).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I'm really asking how to create a keyword field via painless.

Comment: As I said, you have to create the destination index with the new mapping and then execute the _reindex API. You can't define the mapping via painless.